# Php doctrine - Access to more existing Schemas

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I implement Doctrine on Xampp Server. Now I want to access to more than 2 Schemas? I think it would run with the SchemaManager, but I don't have find a way to create the Entities from more than one Schema.

Here is my code:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

// Create a simple "default" Doctrine ORM configuration for Annotations
$isDevMode = true;
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__. "/Entities"), $isDevMode);

// database configuration parameters
$localConn = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'user'=> 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'dbname' => 'shop',
    'port' => '3306',
);

// obtaining the entity manager
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($localConn, $config);
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you miss a `"` in the setting of `$config`

Comment: Sorry, I have this in the code correct. I have deleted it if i copied the code. It runs with one Schema, but I have more than one.

Comment: now you have 1 too much, check the code too